# Sublimetext integration with Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL, bash)

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sublime-text-plugin

Is there a way of executing bash commands from sublimetext?

In many projects it's just better developing with linux tools via the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL, bash) as most tools are built for linux.

In windows, you can run bash commands in a windows-console like this:

```
bash -c "echo \"my bash command here\""
```

Let's say I want to run a very specific build script like this:

```
bash -c "prettier mypath/ && eslint mypath/ --fix"
```

or like this:

```
bash -c "my_very_specific_build_script.sh"
```

or even better, having a hook executing a linter via a hook with: 
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Hooks

```
bash -c "my_linting_script.sh"
```

and then call the script on every "save" like this:

```
"on_post_save_user":
    [
        {
            "command": "bash_execute",
            "args": {
              "command": "my_linting_script.sh",
            }
        }
    ],
```

**This would be a game changer for all of us developers without a mac**

**MY ADVANCE SO FAR**

In Keybindings this works (creates a log when ctrl+alt+b pressed)

```
{
  "keys": ["ctrl+alt+b"], 
  "command": "exec", 
  "args": {
    "cmd": "bash -c \"cd ~ && echo ok >> log.txt\"",
  } 
}
```

And this works in preferences triggered on every "save" using the "hooks" plugin:

```
"on_post_save_user": [
    {
        "command": "exec", 
        "args": {
          "cmd": "bash -c \"cd ~ && echo ok >> log.txt\"",
        },
            "scope": "window"

    }
],
```

**Is this the best way?**

**An attempt at creating a plugin**

I made a simple plugin that successfully runs "top" with bash in windows with WSL.

https://github.com/eduardoarandah/sublime-bash-execute

Just copy BashCommand.py in Packages/User and run in console:

`view.run_command('bash_exec')`

I've never made a sublime plugin, any help would be credited, appreciated and so on.

Comment: The `exec` command can execute arbitrary commands; does that do what you want? (it's what is used to execute build systems, for example).

Comment: Yes, but this works:

    {
      "keys": ["ctrl+alt+b"], 
      "command": "exec", 
      "args": {
        "cmd": "ipconfig",
      } 
    }

And this bash command doesn't work:

    {
      "keys": ["ctrl+alt+b"], 
      "command": "exec", 
      "args": {
        "cmd": "ifconfig",
        "shell": "c:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe"
      } 
    },

Comment: The `shell` argument is a `true`/`false` to indicate if the command should be executed by the shell or launched directly. I would try setting args to just `{"shell_cmd": "c:/windows/system32/bash.exe -c ifconfig"}` and see what happens.

Comment: (`shell_cmd` is a shortcut for setting a command and getting it to run directly by the shell; anything you would normally type into a command prompt or shell window can go in there, including things like `&&` and multiple commands)

Comment: Ah, just noticed your edit; short of creating a plugin that creates a `bash_exec` type command that does what `exec` does but directly in bash, this is likely the best way to go.

Comment: @OdatNurd

A plugin would be AWESOME! 

I made a repo with some advance.

https://github.com/eduardoarandah/sublime-bash-execute


Execute in console: 

view.run_command('bash_exec')

Answer (score 1):

The internal `exec` command can run any arbitrary command that you choose to throw at it, so it's possible to use it directly to do this using that command if so desired.

Something to note is that the `exec` command can be given either `cmd` as a `["list", "of", "strings"]` or `shell_cmd` as `"a single string"`. When using `cmd`, the first item in the list is invoked directly and everything else is passed as arguments, while in the second case the string is passed directly to the shell as is.

Generally for items such as you're mentioning here, you want to use `shell_cmd`; since it's passed directly to the shell to execute, it can contain things such as redirection and chained commands.

As noted in your examples above, you can use `shell_cmd` and prefix any command that you want to execute with `bash -c`, wrapping the rest of the command in double quotes, and the `exec` command will run `bash` and pass it the command that you provided.

It's also possible to create a simple command in Sublime that behaves like `exec` does, while at the same time automatically injecting the appropriate item in there to get bash to execute the command for you.

Such a plugin might look like the following:

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

from Default.exec import ExecCommand


class BashExecCommand(ExecCommand):
    """
    A drop in replacement for the internal exec command that will run the
    given command directly in bash. Use of "shell_cmd" is recommended, but
    some care is taken to convert "cmd" to the appropriate "shell_cmd"
    equivalent.

    For use in key bindings, replace `exec` with `bash_exec` and you're good
    to go. For use in a build system, include the following lines to your
    build to tell Sublime to use this command to execute the build as well as
    how to kill it:

        "target": "bash_exec",
        "cancel": {"kill": True}
    """
    def run(self, **kwargs):
        # If we're being told to kill a running build, short circuit everything
        # and just do it directly. Not really needed, but it's a nice reminder
        # that custom builds need to handle this sort of thing in general.
        if kwargs.get("kill", False):
            return super().run(kill=True)

        # If there is a "cmd" argument, grab it out and convert it into a
        # string. Items in cmd that contain spaces are double quoted so that
        # they're considered a single argument, and all items are joined
        # together.
        cmd = kwargs.pop("cmd", None)
        if cmd is not None:
            cmd = " ".join(["\"%s\"" % s if " " in s else s for s in cmd])

        # If there is a "shell_cmd" argument, then modify it to include the
        # correct prefix to run the command via bash as well as to quote all
        # double quote characters so the shell sees them.
        #
        # This will fall back to the string we just gathered for "cmd" if no
        # shell_cmd is given.
        shell_cmd = kwargs.pop("shell_cmd", cmd)
        if shell_cmd is not None:
            kwargs["shell_cmd"] = "bash -c \"{0}\"".format(
                shell_cmd.replace("\"", "\\\""))

        # Defer to the built in exec command to run the command
        super().run(**kwargs)
```

If you redact away the comments that explain what this is doing, the change is ~20 lines or so. What this is doing is leveraging the internal `exec` command to do all of the heavy lifting for us. Thus we can just modify the arguments to the command automatically and let Sublime take care of the details.

As seen in the code, if a `cmd` argument is provided, it's converted into a string by joining all of the arguments together with space characters. Along the way any argument that contains a space is automatically double quoted so that it conveys properly to the shell.

If `shell_cmd` is provided, it's similarly extracted and converted into a string with a `bash -c` prefix; along the way any double quotes that appear in the command are quoted so that they convey properly to the shell.

Additionally, the converted value of `cmd` is used as the default if no `shell_cmd` is provided; thus if you specify `shell_cmd` that's always what is executed, and if you use `cmd` it's converted into the appropriate `shell_cmd` argument directly.

In use the command that this implements is `bash_exec`, and should be a drop in replacement for uses of `exec` in places where you're calling it directly, such as in key bindings, menu entries, command palette entries, via other commands, etc.

In addition, you can add the following two lines directly to a `sublime-build` file to use this command to execute builds undertaken that way; the first line tells Sublime to use this command instead of `exec` to execute the build, while the second tells it what arguments to pass to the command to get it to cancel a running build.

```json
"target": "bash_exec",
"cancel": {"kill": True},
```

### Caveats

This is really only of use on Windows; on Linux and MacOS Sublime already uses `bash` to execute `shell_cmd` without your having to do anything special. Using `sublime.platform()`, the command could determine if it's being executed on Windows and only rewrite commands on that OS and otherwise leave things alone, if desired.

Note also that I don't personally use WSL on my Windows machines, so this is untested in that environment (but it performs as expected on my Linux box); as such there may still be some tweaks to be made here, such as if `bash` isn't directly on the path or you want it to be configurable.

The last thing to mention is that the code to convert `shell_cmd` and `cmd` into a bash command line may require some more intelligence or subtle tweaks depending on what you're trying to pull off. If things don't seem to do what you expect, the Sublime console displays what command `exec` is running, which may shed some light on things.

Comment: that is amazing!

Can confirm it works

Here is the screenshot

![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4065733/49977046-40fedb00-ff0a-11e8-8633-e3c2d461b0bb.png)


Commands that launch a screen don't work "can't obtain TTY"

My dummy implementation did work with os.system("bash -c \"top\"")


If anybody reading this, add this to your keymap and run ctrl+alt+b

{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+b"], "command": "bash_exec","args":{"cmd":["cd ~/home/scripts","pwd","echo 'ok'"]}}

Comment: OdatNurd Hope you ever get the time to make it a plugin, developing in windows console is pain